# How do I delete '+1' from a column in a data frame, if it contains it?

Tags: python, database

So I'm trying to delete the '+1' from a phone number column in a pandas data frame, if it contains it. Here's what I've tried, to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')

str(df['Phone (Lead Partner)'])
for row in df['Phone (Lead Partner)']:
    split_row = row.split(' ')
    if split_row[0] == '+1':
        split_row.pop(0)
        split_row.concat()
        row = split_row
    else:
        split_row.concat()
        


df['Phone (Lead Partner)'].replace(to_replace = '+1', value = '', regex = True)
for row in df['Phone (Lead Partner)']:
    row.replace(to_replace = '+1', value = '')
 
for idx, val in enumerate(df['Phone (Lead Partner)']):
    if val != 'nan':
        split_val = val.split()
        if split_val[0] == '+1':
            df['Phone (Lead Partner)'][idx].split('+1')
```

These are 3 different ways that I've tried that have not worked. Any ideas on how to make any work, or any other new ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe  is not being updated in the above code.  Inside the "for" loop, only the local variable (row) is being updated and not the dataframe itself.

Suggested code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')

for n,row in enumerate(df['Phone (Lead Partner)']):  # Using enumerate to get the index to update
    split_row = row.replace("+1 ", "", 1)            # Removing "+1 " from the existing entry 
    df['Phone (Lead Partner)'][n] = split_row        # Updating the dataframe
    
print (str(df['Phone (Lead Partner)']))              # Printing the dataframe to confirm
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, What is the third parameter, the 1, in the replace() method?

Comment: The third parameter in replace is "count".   This will replace only the first occurance of "+1 ".    If "count is not specified, then all instances of +1 is replaced.  Ideally in the current phone number scenario,  there should only be one "+1 " string but just safe to add count parameter but not mandatory.